# using the expand/collapse function more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a expand/collapse plugin using jQuery. It works fine when I use it with one `div`.
But it does not work when I try to use it with another `div`. What have I done wrong here?

This is the HTML code I apply the plugin to:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="box-resize">
        <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="item">
                <ul class="item_list">
                    <li>Singapore</li>
                    <li>Singapore</li>
                    <li class="last_item_list">12 hours ago</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-14" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="green_end mapexpand">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="mapexpand" id="mapresize">
                <span>Expand</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="box-resize">
        <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="item">
                <ul class="item_list">
                    <li>Singapore</li>
                    <li>Singapore</li>
                    <li class="last_item_list">12 hours ago</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#"><img class="edit" src="images/icons/pencil.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-14" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="green_end mapexpand">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="mapexpand" id="mapresize">
                <span>Expand</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

This is the actual plugin:

```
var mr=$('#mapresize');
mr.click(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.mapexpand')) { 
        $(this).removeClass('mapexpand').addClass('mapcollapse');
        $("#box-resize").animate({
            height: '100%'
        }, 500, function() {
            mr.find('span').text('collapse');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('mapcollapse').addClass('mapexpand');
        $("#box-resize").animate({
            height: '150px'
        }, 500, function() {
            mr.find('span').text('expand');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: IDS should all be unique...

Comment: this is not a plugin, this is only a function inside an eventHandler.

Comment: But if I use classes instead, when users click expand for one div, both divs expand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ids must be `unique`.You used same id for both divs.It is better to use `class names` instead of ids

`ui-tabs-1 , ui-tabs-2,mapresize...` all these ids you used 2 times

Answer (score 2):

changing you ids to class should work..

```
id="mapresize"
```

to

```
class="mapresize"
```

and use class selector

```
var mr=$('.mapresize');
```

IDS should always be unique.... having two or more elements with same id is invalid..

**note: make sure you change all the elements having same ID to class or make it unique**

Answer (score 0):

Use Classes instead of ID In your function you are not determining which div need to be closed so it will be closing both the div's or not working at all.

You should mention which div need to be collapsed or open. Let your function search the parent of the span which you have clicked for ex:-

```
    <div class = "a">
        <div class - "b">
            <div class = "c">
                <span class = "click-me">Close</span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class = "a">
        <div class - "b">
            <div class = "c">
                <span class = "click-me">Close</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    jquery (".click-me").click (function (e)) {
        if (your-condition) {
            $(this).parents (".a").animate-function-here
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents (".a").animate-function-here
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps